# Does IMF consider the international reputation of a country?

Tags: government-debt, international-economics, default, institutions, financial

Hi I have three question below which I tried searching on internet and read a lot of literature as well. Besides all the literature sources I need to know some practical knowledge of people out there.

1. Does IMF consider international reputation, debt repayment and defaults of a country when they lend money?
2. What arguments can we form according to Michael Tomz reputation theory and the lending decisions of IMF?
3. Do other international financial institutions consider history of defaults and repayments when lending  money?

Comment: You should add more information to this. e.g. what have you read? What are the key arguments in the Michael Tomz reputation theory? Also, would common (economic) sense not imply that the IMF would consider debt repayment and defaults? Countries have credit ratings too